# Variable passing to use path in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org, partials

I'm learning Ruby on Rails by using this [book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/).
I'm stuck on the second exercise from [here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-exercises_edit_form).

My form partial `app/views/users/_form.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: yield(:path)) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

My signup view `app/views/users/new.html.erb` with partial is this:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<% provide(:button_text, 'Create my account') %>
<% provide(:path, signup_path) %>
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my edit view `app/views/users/edit.html.erb` is this:

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<% provide(:button_text, "Save changes") %>
<% provide(:url, user_path) %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form' %>
    <div class="gravatar_edit">
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Change</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I don't know which right path for the **edit view** I have to set with the **provide** method.

With **signup_path** it works fine for the signup view. What I tried for the edit view is:

- `user_path` (currently in the code example)
- `edit_user_path`
- `edit_user_path(@user)` (to pass the user object)

Below the current routing error I got:

[image]

and below that the available routes related to user:

[image]

For example if I don't use provide for the edit view to provide an url, it works fine like here:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

But the goal is to refactor the code using partials, so I need to provide an url for the signup view.

The `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'users/new'

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get    '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post   '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: could  you post the part of your `routes.rb` where you set paths for users?

Comment: You just need to take a look on the process, How rails and their forms work with the active record. Please go with generating the scaffold controller with models. You will definalty learn quickly.

Comment: added the `routes.rb` @mrzasa

Comment: where are you using `edit_user_path(@user)`? needs to be `get` not `patch`

Comment: I'm not using `edit_user_path(@user)`. I tried with it, but it didn't work. And the error with patch appears all the time so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in the end to pass the needed url as requirement from the second exercise [here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-exercises_edit_form), it works with providing just the `user_path`. As I mentioned in my question I tried it already with `user_path`, but what I didn't saw was that I used in the form partial `yield(:path)`, to embed the url, so when you look at my question for the signup view I provided the variable right with `<% provide(:path, signup_path) %>`, but in the edit view I used `<% provide(:url, user_path) %>`. So it's clear that I can't provide a right path from the edit view, even if I set the right one as you can see I described in my tries.

So for those who get also stuck on that exercise after trying on your own and after **looking exactly if you assigned your variables right**. This is my working solution:

The form partial `app/views/users/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: yield(:path)) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The signup view `app/views/users/new.html.erb`:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<% provide(:button_text, 'Create my account') %>
<% provide(:path, signup_path) %>

<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The edit view `app/views/users/edit.html.erb`:

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<% provide(:button_text, "Save changes") %>
<% provide(:path, user_path) %>

<h1>Update your profile</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form' %>
    <div class="gravatar_edit">
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Change</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare path. If you use `resources :users`. Your application will know how to set path. If you declare:

```
@user = User.new
```

the path will be:

```
new_user_path
```

but if you declare:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

the path will be:

```
user_path(id)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html

Comment: I understand that I don't have to declare a path by using `resources :users`, but in this case I need to provide the signup view and the edit view. So the signup view needs the url, in this case the `signup_path`. To provide it I set it like this `form_for(@user, '/signup')` with the signup_path in the **_form partial**. The problem is now as I described in my question, which is the right path for the edit view or how can I avoid to set a path for it so that in the edit view the `form_for` looks like this `form_for(@user)`